# Error using Hector libraries in Scala

Tags: java, scala, hector

I have had the same problem with both hector-core-1.1-2.jar and hector-core-1.1-4.jar (http://hector-client.github.io/hector/build/html/index.html).  When I try to compile a Scala script that uses the Java-based Hector library, I get the following error in sbt:

[error] error while loading Cluster, class file '/path_to_hector/hector-core-1.1-2.jar(me/prettyprint/hector/api/Cluster.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.lang.NullPointerException/)

Does Hector need to be rebuilt a special way to work with Scala?